# DIV positioning, help me align those divs please

Tags: css, position, sidebar

Check out this page: [Link](http://benoitfalardeau.com/temp/test/)

What CSS i should write to make the div #mainframe go on the side of the #sidebar ???

Comment: With a width of 100%? How do u expect to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the width of the mainframe is 100%. use a percentage for the sidebar as well in a combination that equals 100% ie..

```
#sidebar{width:15%;}
#mainframe{width:85%;}
```

It will then sit right next to the sidebar. Be aware that padding and borders will affect the width though.

Comment: Another thing, why is my #header not on top even after putting this

    body {
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
    }

Comment: @Kenobineb try this  p{margin:0}

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by giving both a width %.

```
#mainframe {
    background-color: #756472;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
}

#sidebar {
    background-color: #8C8C8C;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}
```

Comment: Geez! I should have tought about it! Thanks guys :P